# Adding ViewPager into Existing TabHost

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

Hi I would like to add view pager into existing code. What is the best way to add. Here is my RssTabActivitty.java and RssChannelActivity.java.

RssTabActivity is my main activity to initialize the tabs.
RssChannelActivity is load the rss feed.

here is full source code
https://github.com/itcuties/Android-Multicategory-RSS-Reader

```
public class RssTabsActivity extends TabActivity {
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // First, set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_tabs);

    // Then get the TabHost
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    /* *****************
     * Art tab
     */
    Intent artIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    // Set Art category RSS URL
    artIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture?format=xml");

    // The name of the art tab taken from the String resources
    String artTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_art);
    TabSpec artTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(artTabName)
                                .setIndicator(artTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_art))
                                .setContent(artIntent);
    // Add art tab to the TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(artTabSpec);

    /* *****************
     * Tech tab
     */
    Intent techIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    // Set Tech category RSS URL
    techIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews?format=xml");

    // Tech tab name taken from the string resources
    String techTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_tech);
    TabSpec techTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(techTabName)
                                 .setIndicator(techTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_tech))
                                 .setContent(techIntent);
    // Add tech tab to the TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(techTabSpec);


    /* *****************
     * Sports tab
     */
    Intent sportsIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
    // Set Sports category RSS URL
    sportsIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/sportsNews?format=xml");

    // Sports tab name - string resources
    String sportsTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_sports);
    TabSpec sportsTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(sportsTabName)
                                   .setIndicator(sportsTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_sports))
                                   .setContent(sportsIntent);
    // Add sports tab to the TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(sportsTabSpec);


    // Set current tab to Technology
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
```

}

`public class RssChannelActivity extends Activity {`

`// A reference to this activity
private RssChannelActivity local;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_channel);

    // Get the RSS URL that was set in the RssTabActivity
    String rssUrl = (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("rss-url");

    // Set reference to this activity
    local = this;

    GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

    // Start process RSS task
    task.execute(rssUrl);

}

/**
 * This class downloads and parses RSS Channel feed.
 * 
 * @author itcuties
 *
 */
private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {
    @Override
    protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            // Create RSS reader
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

            // Parse RSS, get items
            return rssReader.getItems();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RssChannelActivity", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {

        // Get a ListView from the RSS Channel view
        ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssChannelListView);

        // Create a list adapter
        ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        // Set list adapter for the ListView
        itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set list view item click listener
        itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
    }
}`

}

Answer (score 0):

To add a view pager to your activity:

1. Add the ViewPager resource to your activity resource:

   ```
   <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
       android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="top"
       android:background="#33b5e5"
       android:paddingBottom="4dp"
       android:paddingTop="4dp"
       android:textColor="#fff" />
   ```
2. Create the fragment resource of your pager:

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/section_label"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
3. Create the fragment class of your fragment:

   public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
           /**
            * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
            * fragment.
            */
           public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

   ```
       public DummySectionFragment() {
       }

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                   container, false);
           TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                   .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
           dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                   ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
           return rootView;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create the adapter class of your pager:

   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   ```
       public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
           super(fm);
       }

       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
           // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
           // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
           Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
           Bundle args = new Bundle();
           args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
           fragment.setArguments(args);
           return fragment;
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           // Show 3 total pages.
           return 3;
       }

       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
           switch (position) {
           case 0:
               return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
           case 1:
               return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
           case 2:
               return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
           }
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Use the pager in your activity (Your activity must extend FragmentActivity):

   SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
   ViewPager mViewPager;
   mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
   mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);